# IE7 & jQuery-1.6.2: List items being moved down go under the containing elements (multi list sorting)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

My code on a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SMqR9/33/

The javascript for quicker reference:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {

    $j("#sort_content_41,#sort_content_40,#sort_content_42,#sort_content_39").sortable({
        connectWith: '.section-content',
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        zIndex: 1004,
        cursor: 'crosshair'
    });
    $j("#sort_sections").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        connectWith: '.sections',
        axis: 'y',
        zIndex: 1003,
        cursor: 'crosshair'
    });
});

$j(function() {
    $j("section-content").sortable({
        connectWith: "section-content",
        dropOnEmpty: true
    });
    $j(".section-content").disableSelection();
});
```

Now, from a question earlier, someone came up with this code that fixes the z-index thing in IE:

```
$j('ul').bind('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($j.browser.msie && $j.browser.version < '9.0') $j(this).closest('.section').css('z-index', '5000');
});
if ($j.browser.msie && $j.browser.version < '9.0') {
    $j('ul').bind('mouseup', function(e) {
        $j(this).closest('.section').css('z-index', '1000');
    });
}
```

which is fine for jQuery 1.3.2 (what I was on previously), but because of IE9, I needed to upgrade to the latest jQuery. When I use the IE < 9 code from above, I can only move the list items once. After that, everything stops. =\
There are no errors / warnings in the webkit inspector. =\

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused as to your actual question. Which browser are you seeing a problem with? (I just tried your jsfiddle in IE8 -- which would run the "below IE9" code) and it's fine, but you're mentioning a webkit inspector, which implies that you're seeing the problem in Chrome/Safari?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem just be removing the e.stopPropagation();

not sure why it was there in the first place. =\

Comment: The `stopPropagation();` was to prevent the MouseDown event from bubbling up to parent `<div>` tags etc. Depending on your implementation it's either useful, or breaks it. In this case it seems to do the latter after the update, so I'm sorry if this did cause you headaches, since it wasn't exactly needed :-)